# Making WCF Service Async in 3.5 Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, async-await

We have used 3.5 Framework for our product development as it developed a long time back. We have developed WCF service which is consumed by many clients ( windows service) and every day we get lots of request to our WCF service method and since it works synchronously it's blocking subsequent requests.

We are thinking now to make it Async so that it improves our performance and our server doesn't become slow.

The confusion is we just want to make a change and make the async method and don't want to change the client side as its windows service and installed on many clients.

So making the async method at server side would help? Or must we change the client side as well?

as it's in the 3.5 .net Framework we will be using [AsyncBridge](https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge) Nuget package which is built for the 2.x Framework to support Asynchronous operation.

Can someone guide me here?

For testing purposes, I have created one async WCF operation contract as follows

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  Task<bool> GetAsyncTestData(string names);
```

And the implementation:

```
async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> GetAsyncTestData(string Names)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => true);
    return false;
}
```

So If I make test client and make 1000 calls will it work async or it will create a deadlock?

Comment: How will the client side consume the service, if there is no `Task` class in 3.5? I doubt that you can do that without rewriting the client side as well.